# windows sdk: wininet.lib exists in x86 but not x64 folder

Tags: windows, linker-errors, unreal-engine4

while I was compiling unreal engine 4 source code following this link

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/DevelopmentSetup/BuildingUnrealEngine/

it failed with message:

cannot open file "wininet.lib"(when compiling texturesharesdk.vcxproj), "dbghelp.lib"(ue4.vcxproj)

so I checked my windows sdk folder, and found out that:

1. wininet.lib only exists in lib/x86 folder.
2. dbghelp.lib doesn't exit in those folders, while dbghelp.dll is in debuggers folder

But my platform config is Win64 according to the above link, so I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Update to windows sdk 10.0.22621.0 solved the texturesharesdk compiling issues. ue4 main project is compiling, but I've checked that there is a wininet.lib in the correct folder